# Reading direction stored in pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I'm working with a microntroller, programming it in C.
I want to store a value in a certain address. so I declared the next pointer and definition which I got from the manufacturer reference manual

```
volatile unsigned long *mainPtr  = (volatile unsigned long *)0x00009000;

#define WRITE_ADDR(x) \
(*(volatile unsigned long *)(void *)(&__IPSBAR[(0x04000000 + (x))]))

unsigned char Write_Data((volatile unsigned long *mainPtr, uint32 data)
{
  WRITE_ADDR(*mainPtr) = data;        // this one doesn't work
  WRITE_ADDR(0x00009000) = data;      // this one does work
}

int main()
{
// calling the function
 Write_Data(mainPtr, 01234U);
}
```

Does anyone know where is my error?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `WRITE_ADDR(*mainPtr)` is `WRITE_ADDR(*0x00009000)` which is obviously not the same as `WRITE_ADDR(0x00009000)`

Comment: Do `WRITE_ADDR(mainPtr)` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WRITE_ADDR(*mainPtr)` is essentially the same as `WRITE_ADDR(*0x00009000)`. That is, it passes the dereferenced pointer rather than  the pointer itself. The macro requires the pointer (not the value it points to). So the correct macro syntax would be `WRITE_ADDR(mainPtr)`.

But I think even that is incorrect. The macro actually expects the parameter to be an integer type and not a pointer. If a pointer is passed in `(0x04000000 + (x))` will result in pointer arithmetic which will be the wrong value. So really `mainPtr` cannot be directly used with the macro without first casting it to an integer type such as `uintptr_t`.

Comment: I think that in this particular case the value is used as an offset (by `0x04000000`). So a `uintptr_t` would do, buy might it be more correct to use `ptrdiff_t`?